# Python sudoku solver skipping value problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku

I am trying to make a sudoku solver with Python.

The idea is for every value, if its 0 which is means blank, find the numbers in the square,x and y row.

Then apply a for loop in range (1,10) and if the value is not in the list of found numbers, change the value with 0.

However the program skips some blank values.

For example:

```
[[8, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 7],
[0, 6, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0],
[0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4],
[0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7, 5, 0],
[3, 8, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 4, 2]]
```

this input gives this:

```
[8, 1, 4, 9, 3, 6, 5, 2, 7]
[0, 6, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 9, 8]
[5, 7, 3, 2, 8, 0, 4, 1, 6]
[2, 9, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 3, 6, 7, 2, 8, 9, 0, 4]
[4, 0, 8, 0, 9, 5, 2, 7, 3]
[6, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 8, 9]
[9, 2, 0, 4, 1, 0, 7, 5, 0]
[3, 8, 0, 5, 7, 9, 6, 4, 2]
```

I didn't understand the reason.My code is here:

```py
class Sudoku:


    sudoku = [[8, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 7],
              [0, 6, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0],
              [0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4],
              [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
              [0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7, 5, 0],
              [3, 8, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 4, 2]]


    def find_square(self,line_x,line_y):
        square_list = []

        if line_y <= 2:
            line_y = 0
        if line_y > 2 and line_y <= 5:
            line_y = 3
        if line_y > 5:
            line_y = 6

        if line_x <= 2:
            line_x = 0
        if line_x > 2 and line_x <= 5:
            line_x = 3
        if line_x > 5:
            line_x = 6

        for i in range(0,3):
            for j in range(0,3):
                list = self.sudoku[line_y + i]
                if list[line_x + j] != 0:
                    square_list.append(list[line_x + j])
        return square_list

    def find_x(self,line_x):
        temperory_list = []

        for line in self.sudoku:
            if line[line_x] != 0:
                temperory_list.append(line[line_x])
        return temperory_list

    def find_y(self,line_y):
        temperory_list = []
        for i in self.sudoku[line_y]:
            if i != 0:
                temperory_list.append(i)
        return temperory_list

    def take_numbers(self,line_x,line_y):
        temperory_list = []
        list = []

        for i in self.find_square(line_x,line_y):
            temperory_list.append(i)

        for i in self.find_x(line_x):
            temperory_list.append(i)

        for i in self.find_y(line_y):
            temperory_list.append(i)

        for i in temperory_list:
            if i not in list:
                list.append(i)
        return list

    def solve(self):
        for y in range(9):
            for x in range(9):
                if self.sudoku[y][x] == 0:
                    list = self.take_numbers(x,y)
                    for i in range(1,10):
                        if i not in list:
                            self.sudoku[y][x] = i
                            break

    def print_sudoku(self):
        for i in self.sudoku:
            print(i)


test = Sudoku()
test.solve()
test.print_sudoku()
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to use the name `list` for a variable because you're replacing the built in type `list` (I think there should be a beginners mode in Pythoin where such things are flagged automatically when you run the code, but that's a different topic) - I find it helpful to make name of variables that hold a list be a plural by adding s on the end, I'd suggest changing your use of `list` to e.g. `numbers` and then you can iterate over the list using e.g. `for number in numbers:`

Comment: I think the 0s in your result are where your 'solve()` function didn't find a solution - your code doesn't appear to handle this at all.

Comment: This might be an opportunity for you to improve your own debugging skills.  The following article provides several useful debugging techniques [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b).